# In Apache Nifi, is it possible to drop some objects based on a condition

Tags: json, apache-nifi

In Apache Nifi, am reading some logs from S3 and which are json objects in text files, I split them with SplitText processor, now I want to filter out some objects based on attribute 'source=es_logs'. Is there any processor for this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`RouteOnAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/index.html) processor. This can be a boolean match routing to `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE` relationships, or an *n-many* match routing to an arbitrary number of relationships.